# How to access MatrixFactorizationModel inside JavaRDD

Tags: parallel-processing, machine-learning, apache-spark, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to run a batch process to calculate the recommendations for all users.

Right now running it on movielens dataset.

I am trying to get the Rating[] of the recommendedProducts for user inside RDD and that throws the error:
**org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations;**

I understand it must be because RDD cannot be accessed another RDD but what is the alternate way of executing same code:

```
final MatrixFactorizationModel model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "S3 PATH FOR MODEL");

    JavaRDD<Integer> userIdRDD = data.map(
            new Function<String, Integer>() {
                public Integer call(String s) {
                    String[] sarray = s.split(",");
                    return Integer.parseInt(sarray[0]);
                }
            }
    );

    userIdRDD.distinct().foreach(
            new VoidFunction<Integer>() {
                public void call(Integer id) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("User Id: " + id);
                    Rating[] recommendProducts = model.recommendProducts(id, 10);

                    List<Recommendations> userRecommendations = new ArrayList<Recommendations>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < recommendProducts.length; i++) {
                        userRecommendations.add(new Recommendations(i+1, id, recommendProducts[i].product()));
                    }

                    RedshiftUtility.batchInsert(jdbcURL, userRecommendations);
                }
            }
    );
```

If I convert userIdRDD to List using collect method then I can iterate over that List and save the recommendations but I assume that the processing is happening at driver and not in clusters. I want to run the processing and db insert in the parallel env only rather than at driver.

> > EDIT

I have edited the code to run using one RDD. How can I test whether it will run in parallel in spark cluster?

```
    JavaSparkContext jsc = SparkContextFactory.getSparkContext(accessKey, secretKey);
    SparkContext sc = jsc.sc();

    final MatrixFactorizationModel model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "s3n://redshift-temp-copy/model");

    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Rating[]>> userRecommendationsRDD = model.recommendProductsForUsers(100).toJavaRDD();

    userRecommendationsRDD.foreach(
            new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Object, Rating[]>>() {
                public void call(Tuple2<Object, Rating[]> objectTuple2) throws Exception {

                    List<Recommendations> userRecommendations = new ArrayList<Recommendations>();

                    for(int i = 0; i < objectTuple2._2().length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Object Tuple: "+i+" > "+objectTuple2._1().toString()+" > "+objectTuple2._2()[i].product());
                        userRecommendations.add(new Recommendations(i+1, Integer.parseInt(objectTuple2._1().toString()), objectTuple2._2()[i].product()));
                    }

                    RedshiftUtility.batchInsert(jdbcURL, userRecommendations);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: You have edited the question adding a different question. If the answer provided is correct please accept it and ask your "new question" in a new post!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to do a nested RDD transformation which refers to the following issue [SPARK-924](https://spark-project.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-924). This issue won't be ever fixed.

The reason why it won't be fixed is that you might want to transfer over the network a whole RDD which is a problem if it contains a lot of data.

If it does not contain a lot of data, you might and you should use an array or something like it.

So while nested RDDs are not possible, you can certainly have collections within an RDD.

For example, our groupBy returns an RDD of sequences of values for each key.

So you'll need to find a work around using nested RDDs.

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737308/spark-work-around-nested-rdd/30738720#30738720) about a work around this problem.